# Create public static var dynamically in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, variables

Is it possible to create public static vars in a loop?
Something like:

```
for(var i:uint=0;i<22;i++)
{
public static var ("Name"+String(i+1)) = Texture(....);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No. Not I have seen or heard of yet.The loop needs to run inside a method definition and you cannot declare `public static var` inside a method. Variable names cannot be dynamic either, the compiler should check for syntax errors at compile time and how would it know if you are naming the variables at run time ? Dynamic names for local variables aren't allowed.

For your purpose , you can use an [Array](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html),[Dictionary](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html) or [Object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html) to store more than one values by looping through . But then , you cannot use `public static` inside the loop.

```
var myVarMap:Object = {};
for(var i:uint=0;i<22;i++)
{
   myVarMap['Name' +i]  = Texture(....);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although, I think The New Idiot's answer to use a static Array should serve your purpose and that would keep the logic more readable. But, to answer your question, if we can create public static property on a class dynamically: yes, you can by using the prototype object. See code below.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class dingAS3 extends Sprite
    {
        public function dingAS3()
        {
            DynClass.init();

            var a:DynClass = new DynClass;
            for(var i:String in a)
            {
                trace(i + '-->' + a[i]);
            }

            var b:DynClass = new DynClass;

            DynClass.prototype["prop0"] = "Hello";

            trace('b: ' + b["prop0"]);
        }
    }
}


class DynClass
{
    public static function init():void
    {
        for(var i:uint=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            DynClass.prototype["prop"+i] = i;
        }
    }
}
```

The output for above code would be something like:

```
prop1-->1
prop3-->3
prop2-->2
prop0-->0
prop4-->4
b: Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, no as The New Idiot points out,
but there approaches that can help.

You can actually generate some code using libraries that do ABC(actionscript bytecode) manipulation (like [as3swf](https://github.com/claus/as3swf), [as3-commons-bytecode](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-bytecode/)) but that's way to complicated for your scenario. catholicon's solution is a lot simpler, but it's also a good idea to be careful when using dynamic classes.

I assume you have a folder with assets and you want to generate an assets class based on that. It should only be a matter of using any sort of language you're comfortable with that can scan your filesystem: cmd/bash/c/c++/python/java or even javascript though JSFL in the Flash IDE or actionscript 3 as a minimal AIR tool to generate this assets class for you.

Here's a quick example using Python:

```
import sys,os,re

classTemplate = "package{\n\n\tpublic class %s{\n%s\n\t}\n}" #template for empty class with variables placeholder
varTemplate   = "\t\tpublic static var %s = new Texture('%s');\n" #variable template with 2 placeholders: variable name and file path
vars = "" #all vars to be placed in the class variables place holder

clean = lambda varStr: re.sub('\W|^(?=\d)','_', varStr) #cleanup the filename so it's a valid actionscript variable name

if(len(sys.argv) == 4): #if we have all the arguments
    f = sys.argv[1]
    if(os.path.exists(f) == False): #check if the path exists
        print f+' does not exist'
        pass

    if(f != None and os.path.isdir(f)): # also if it's a directory
        files = []
        for (dirpath, dirname, filenames) in os.walk(f): #travers the path and remember files
            files.extend(filenames)
            break
        for tf in files: # for each file
            var = clean(tf) # create a variable
            vars += varTemplate % (var,dirpath+os.sep+tf) # replace the variable placeholders/tokens and append to all class vars
        asClass = open(sys.argv[3],'w') #finally open the output file
        asClass.write(classTemplate % (sys.argv[2],vars)) # replace and write the class
        asClass.close() # and close the file
    else:
        print f +' is not a directory'
```

If you save this as `assetgen.py` for example you can run it like so:

```
python /path/to/assetgen.py /path/to/your/assets_dir AS3ClassName /path/to/write/AS3ClassName.as
```

So a short test on my machine would look like:

```
python ~/Desktop/assetgen.py ~/Documents/assets/240x240_240x230_pxl/240x240/1-1 Assets1_1 ~/Desktop/Assets1_1.as
```

Which produced:

```
package{

    public class Assets1_1{
        public static var _01_bmp = new Texture('/Users/hm/Downloads/240x240_240x230_pxl/240x240/1-1/01.bmp');
        public static var _02_bmp = new Texture('/Users/hm/Downloads/240x240_240x230_pxl/240x240/1-1/02.bmp');
        public static var _03_bmp = new Texture('/Users/hm/Downloads/240x240_240x230_pxl/240x240/1-1/03.bmp');
        public static var _04_bmp = new Texture('/Users/hm/Downloads/240x240_240x230_pxl/240x240/1-1/04.bmp');
        public static var _05_bmp = new Texture('/Users/hm/Downloads/240x240_240x230_pxl/240x240/1-1/05.bmp');

    }
}
```

If you're using Ant for example (which can integrate into IDE like eclipse/FlashBuilder/FDT), you can easily generate a task to regenerate the class as assets change/update in your project.

Feel free to generate variables names as you with, add an extra command line argument for specify the actionscript package, etc.

As mentioned, the above script (traversing an asset directory and replacing strings to generate an actionscript class file) can be written in a language you're comfortable with.